# Delimiting results in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to extract data from a column `PRODUCT_ID` which contains values like

```
101-1*S5-04004PC0
13-4*1.01.11
```

I want to get these values in two separate columns, delimited by `*`. Can someone please help?

```
select PRODUCT_ID 
from TABLE1;
```

I also have some data like this 101-1*S5-04004PC0*123 (meaning having two delimiters) but i just want the query to separate it when it finds the first * from left.

Comment: Just use `charindex` to find positions of `*` in string and then extract string parts with `substring`

Comment: Once you separate these values you should consider keeping them that way. I know sometimes we are stuck with legacy code but stuffing multiple values into a single tuple like this violates 1NF and is extremely painful to work with. If at all possible modify your table so don't have to do this all the time. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
select left(product_id, charindex('*', product_id + '*') - 1) as col1,
       substring(product_id, charindex('*', product_id + '*') + 1, len(product_id)) as col2
```

The `+ '*'` is to prevent errors if `'*'` does not appear in the column.

Comment: Thanks, but i also want to remove the delimiter sign '*'

Comment: in the result, i see it like this '101-1' and '*S5-04004PC0'

Comment: Thanks, your query works perfectly, just need to remove the '*' from the result

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `CHARINDEX()` , `SUBSTRING()` and `REVERSE` :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Product_id, charindex('*', product_id ) + 1) as Col1,
       SUBSTRING(REVERESE(Product_id), charindex('*', product_id ) + 1) as Col2
FROM TABLE1
```